# How can I change the structure of an AngularJS get request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-http

I have the following states as part of an AngularJS app:

```
.state('app.stages', {
      url: '/stages',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/stages.html',
      controller: 'StagesCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('app.stage', {
url: '/stages/:stageId',
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/stage.html',
    controller: 'StageCtrl'
  }
}
```

The controllers associated are:

```
controller('StagesCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
$http.get("http://localhost/apistages")
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.stages = response.data;
});
})

.controller('StageCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost/apistage/',
    params: {stageId: $stateParams.stageId}
 }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.stage = response.data;
 }, function errorCallback(response) {

  });
});
```

The stages list works well, but the query in the stage controller tries to access http://localhost/apistage/?stageId=43 which results in a 500 (Internal Server Error).

The URL format that I need to use is http://localhost/apistage/43 . How can I adjust the query to fetch that URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then don't use `params` options on $http GET request. Instead just use simple string concatenation on URL while making call to service

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost/apistage/'+$stateParams.stageId //append state parameter in URL itself
})
```

For REST API I'd highly recommend you to use [**`ngResource`($resource)**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) module of angular. Which has good capability to deal with rest calls.

Comment: I had tried this, but late nights and being stuck in PHP for a while led to me using a . for the concatenation instead of a +. Such a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use two controllers. Use only one controller and use $routeParams to get the url parameter. Here now you check if parameter is present or not and differentiate your logic as required. You can use the following code:
`var stageId = $routeParams.stageId;
If(stageId)
   Do something
else
   Do something different`